# How to get the logical data usage within a Cassandra cluster

Tags: java, nosql, cassandra

We could look at the physical bytes on disk, but that number includes all the replicas. So I am wondering is there a good approach to get the logical data usage (the real meaningful data size) within the cluster without iterating all of them? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. Even the nodetool cfstats which shows live sstable size, includes the replica. You can iterate and add all and divide by the number of replicas you have to get a tough estimate of one.